# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 103059952 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 45MB until OOM

Tags: java, android

I've done some research, but haven't had any luck - especially since most answers have to do with a VM.  I'm testing my app on a physical phone - Samsung Galaxy S4.  My app crashes, before the menu screen loads... with the error below.  I don't understand why because I don't have any large images (I checked..the largest png file I have is only 224 KB).

Any idead how to fix? Thanks in advance...

```
03-07 10:19:56.199  18473-18493/com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 7662
Process: com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.android, PID: 18473
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 103059952 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 45MB until OOM
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
        at com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.screens.MenuScreen.buildScoresWindowLayer(MenuScreen.java:499)
        at com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.screens.MenuScreen.rebuildStage(MenuScreen.java:152)
        at com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.screens.MenuScreen.show(MenuScreen.java:128)
        at com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.screens.DirectedGame.setScreen(DirectedGame.java:51)
        at com.packtpub.libgdx.outtacluck.ChickenMain.create(ChickenMain.java:51)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:243)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1520)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

Here's the function that triggers the error:

```
private Table buildScoresWindowLayer() {
    scores = new Window("Top 5 High Scores", skinLibgdx);

    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("data/highscores.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file.reader());
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;
    try {
        line = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (line != null){
        lines.add(line);
    }


    scores.add(lines.get(0));
    scores.add(lines.get(0));

    scores.add(lines.get(0));
    scores.add(lines.get(0));
    scores.add(lines.get(0));


    // + Character Skin: Selection Box (White, Gray, Brown)
    //scores.add(buildOptWinSkinSelection()).row();

    // + Debug: Show FPS Counter
    //scores.add(buildOptWinDebug()).row();

    // + Separator and Buttons (Save, Cancel)
   scores.add(buildScoresWinButtons()).pad(10, 0, 10, 0);

    // Make options window slightly transparent
    scores.setColor(1, 1, 1, 0.8f);

    // Hide options window by default
    showScoresWindow(false, false);

    if (debugEnabled)
        scores.debug();

    // Let TableLayout recalculate widget sizes and positions
    scores.pack();

    // Move options window to bottom right corner
    scores.setPosition(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH - scores.getWidth() - 150, 50);
    return scores;
}
```

Comment: `while (line != null){ lines.add(line); }` when is this supposed to end ?

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is never ending! Bring it to a conclusion ;)